# Why componentDidMount gets called multiple times in react.js & redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I read `componentDidMount` gets called only once for initial rendering but I'm seeing it's getting rendered multiple times.

It seems I created a recursive loop.

- componentDidMount dispatches action to fetch data
- upon receiving the data, it fires success action to store the data in redux state.
- a parent react component is connected to redux store and has `mapStateToProps` for the entry that just changed in the above step
- parent renders child components (which is programmatically selected via variable)
- the child component's componentDidMount gets called again
- it dispaches action to fetch data

I think that's what's happening. I may be wrong.

How can I stop the loop?

Here's the code for programmatically rendering child components.

```
 function renderSubviews({viewConfigs, viewConfig, getSubviewData}) {

   return viewConfig.subviewConfigs.map((subviewConfig, index) => {
     let Subview = viewConfigRegistry[subviewConfig.constructor.configName]
     let subviewData = getSubviewData(subviewConfig)

     const key = shortid.generate()
     const subviewLayout = Object.assign({}, subviewConfig.layout, {key: key})
     return (
       <div
         key={key}
         data-grid={subviewLayout}
         >
         <Subview
           {...subviewData}
           />
       </div>
     )
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A component instance will only get mounted once and unmounted when it gets deleted. In your case it gets deleted and recreated.

The point of the `key` prop is to help React find the previous version of the same component. That way it can update a previous component with new props rather than create a new one.

React can often work fine without a key, the exception being a list with items. It wants a key there so it can keep track when items get rearranged, created or deleted.

In your case, you are explicitly telling React that your component is different from the previous one. You're giving a new key on each render. This forces React to treat the previous instance as having been deleted. Any children of that component are also unmounted and dismantled.

What you ought to do is not (ever) generate a key at random. Keys should always be based on the identity of the data a component is displaying. If it's not a list item you probably don't need a key. If it is a list item, it's much better to use a key derived from the data's identity, such as an ID property, or maybe a combination of multiple fields.

If generating a random key would have been the correct thing to do, React would have just taken care of that for you.

You should place your initial fetch code in the root of your React tree, usually that's `App`. Don't put it in some random child. At least you should put it in a component that exist for the lifetime of your app.

The main reason to put it in `componentDidMount` is so it doesn't run on the server, because server-side components never get mounted. This is important for universal rendering. Even if you're not doing this now, you might do this later, and being prepared for it is a best practice.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer. I returned to reword my question because what I asked was not clear and here's an answer that explains *why* it's happening. Thank you

Comment: I learned a ton from this answer! Very elegant approach from react

Comment: Is there any circumstance in which a top level component hit directly by Routing from the address bar will hit componentDidMount more than once?  I am pretty sure I have seen this.   If there is such a case, is there a way WITHIN the component, short of the internal hackery in the original post, to set the component's key to perhaps prevent it?  I don't see why it *would* happen or should be necessary.  But perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: A component will be mounted only once. It could be the component got deleted and later recreated or possibly there is more than one instance. React wouldn't delete your component but a patent component might.

Comment: So I just ran into a similar situation. I saw two mounts and never an un-mount. What happened was I had two routes one that when to /wizard and one that went to /wizard/:id this caused two components to mount but only one rendered. I was having a hard time tracking down why state changes were reflected in the debugger in some cases and not the other. I removed the route without the params and the world is good again. So it can seem that the component mounted twice but it was really two separate instances of the same component. I'm not sure if there is a good way to debug that or not.

Comment: @DDS That's a great explanation. Thank you. I want to ask you something though to make sure that I'm understanding you correctly. In paragraph 6 of your post you said, "You should place your initial fetch code in the root of your react tree. Don't put it in some random child." When you say that, Do you mean that all fetches that are global (and don't have any contingencies) should be made in the app component?

Answer (score 48):

Multiple `componentDidMount` calls may be caused by using `<React.StrictMode>` around your component. After removing it double calls are gone.

This is intended behavior to help detect unexpected side effects. You can read more about it [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). It happens only in development environment, while in production `componentDidMount` is called only once even with `<React.StrictMode>`.

*For your specific case, answer by DDS is correct. However, Strict Mode is also a common problem and this question comes up high in google results.*

Comment: <comp key="anythingunique"/> did not work for me. removing strict mode did the trick!

Answer (score 17):

Just a [quote](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/429#issuecomment-151990676):

> It's just because we do 2 initial renders in dev mode to avoid getting warnings about mismatched client/server markup when we introduce the devtools. Doesn't affect production.

First picture - development mode, second one - production mode.

[image: development mode]
[image: production mode]

Answer (score 4):

I experienced my componentDidMount being called twice. I debugged my component tree until I reached the root index. Then, I tried removing the <React.StrictMode> and it worked. componentDidMount was called only once.
This is because <React.StrictMode> intentionally invokes certain React lifecycle methods twice, including componentDidMount, to help detect potential issues with the code. <React.StrictMode> is designed to highlight potential problems, such as side effects, and warn about them during development.