# React ComponentDidMount being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to make a fetch api call inside of `AccountItem.js` like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // I am calling console.log("item mounted"); here
    var url = "myurl" + this.props.portalId;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({account: data.Items}));
}
```

Then inside my `Home.js` it renders:

```
componentDidMount() {
   console.log("home mounted");
}
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Account Dashboard
        <AccountItem portalId={this.props.portalId}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am logging my fetch into the console and it is being called three times. The flow is I am on the login page (mounted once upon load), I login which redirects me to the home page which itself renders . At this point in my console I see:

`Login mounted // initial load, now I click login
Login mounted // Renders again then redirects to homepage
Item mounted
Home mounted
Item mounted
Home mounted
Item mounted // Why is this happening 3 times?`

I am new to react, please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974210/why-componentdidmount-gets-called-multiple-times-in-react-js-redux

Comment: Are you using external state libraries or anything else?

Comment: @Li357 No I am not

Comment: @Apolozeus checked out that question. I'm not generating any keys in my `Home` or `AccountItem`. Any other ideas what may be the cause?

Comment: It could be the reason, you can install react developer tools and see if any warning message is there.

Comment: Can you please show where are you writing the console log

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay I have updated the post. I am calling console log at the beginning of each componentDidMount()

Comment: @Apolozeus I downloaded the dev tools and am not receiving any warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem was in my Router I was rendering this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    // Other routes here
                        <this.PrivateRoute path="/home" exact component={<Home .... />} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

And my private route was:

```
PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
                <Route {...rest} render={() => (
                    this.state.isAuthenticated
                    ? <Component {...this.props} portalId={this.state.portalId}/>
                    : <Redirect to="/" />
                )}/> 
            )
```

So the home was being rendered multiple times. I simply just swapped out the `<Home />` inside the router to `{Home}`

Comment: @BernardoFerreiraBastosBraga I cannot for 2 days

Comment: Hi, @Vincent, Can you share the project on codepen? I am having same issue, but can't figure out with your solution.