# componentDidMount() function runs twicely

Tags: reactjs

```
export class ClassName extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {articles:this.articles,
                      loading:false};
          console.warn("constructer");

      }
        componentDidMount(){
          console.warn("componentdidmount");                    
        }
      render() {
      console.warn("render");
    return (
      <div >
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

output

```
constructed
render
componentdidmount
componentdidmount
```

I can't able to figure out what the issue is, I have gone through docs but still not able to resolve it

please do help

Comment: Possibly `React.StrictMode` is causing that issue, you can try to remove it that may help you

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904109/18311567) help?